Looking for medieval Star Wars type movie
I'm looking for a movie from Kroger Video in USA (English) around 1996 or 1997.
I DO NOT remember the title.
A boy/young adult grew up on a farm in an evil empire. (Sound familiar?)
He teams up with a wizard/knight who used to know his father. As a child he was lied to about his father, by being told he was JUST a farmer. They had to go on a quest to fight an evil wizard/ex knight of the old kingdom. They rescue a princes along the way who turns out to be someone close. They travel through a forest and are caught in nets by little people, who live in trees. (No they were not completely covered in fur!) Everything happens on ONE planet, horses, not space ships. But yes, it was a very very long time ago.
I was laughing 2-3 minutes in about the whole Star Wars theme of it all. Friends I was watching with took about 20 minutes to realize it.

"I was laughing 2-3 minutes in about the whole Star Wars theme of it all." Sure, Star Wars in the end is a very primitive fairy tale. In space. No surprise it resembles other such movies and stories so much.

I am looking for it, not a quiz. If it was a quiz, I WOULD BE the winner. My prize would be the movie title!.   I agree on it being a primitive tale, Lucas based it on the Kurasawa movie "The Hidden Fortress".  In how many of the other movies that resemble it though, does an orphan boy growing up on his uncles farm, join up with a wizard/knight who tells him his father used to be one too, but his uncle has been untruthful with him in an attempt to keep him safe for the evil empire? Not to mention the "tree people" and the misplaced princess. I wish I could put up a bounty for this movie title.

I remember this movie, but only vaguely...it seemed like the wizard/knight was played by Dennis Quaid but I think that I am getting Dragonheart mixed up with the movie that you are describing. Can you say what decade you think the movie was made in? Was it new in 96 or 97?

Yes, I was working in a video store at the time, and they let me take home some new releases every week, so I could chat with customers about them. It was a great job, but the company closed down. It was  definitely new in '96-'97.

Could it be Spaceballs?

No. No one was actually in space... they were on ONE planet, with no visible means of space travel. It was a medieval world, whose fastest mode of transport was a horse.

I think at the end, they found the wizard's cave and he had "magic" items from the future... like tripod-mounted laser cannons and such. Every other part of the movie lined up almost perfectly to the original trilogy, except I do not recall whether or not anyone's arm was chopped off.

I do not recall EVER seeing a movie trailer, It may have gone straight to VHS. I just saw it on the shelf, I don't even recall why I picked it up, probably just because it was in the new-release section.

I was thinking Eragon,  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449010, but it is a decade too late.

I have tried several websites that organize movie releases by year, and searched for keywords. I'm just not hitting the right set of them I guess. Any obscure search sites you may know of that I don't?

Sounds very similar to "Your Highness" but that film is from 2011, not 1996/7.
P.S. I would've commented instead of "answering" but was unable to.
:
Plot summary

"Throughout history, tales of chivalry have burnished the legends of brave, handsome knights who rescue fair damsels, slay dragons and conquer evil. But behind many a hero is a good-for-nothing younger brother trying just to stay out of the way of those dragons, evil and trouble in general. As two princes on a daring mission to save their land, they must rescue the heir apparent's fiancée before their kingdom is destroyed. Thadeous (McBride) has spent his life watching his perfect older brother Fabious (Franco) embark upon valiant journeys and win the hearts of his people. Tired of being passed over for adventure, adoration and the throne, he's settled for a life of wizard's weed, hard booze and easy maidens. But when Fabious' bride-to-be, Belladonna (Zooey Deschanel), gets kidnapped by the evil wizard Leezar (Justin Theroux), the king gives his deadbeat son an ultimatum: Man up and help rescue her or get cut off. Half-assedly embarking upon his first quest, Thadeous joins Fabious to trek across the perilous outlands and free the princess. Joined by Isabel (Natalie Portman)-an elusive warrior with a dangerous agenda of her own-the brothers must vanquish horrific creatures and traitorous knights before they can reach Belladonna. If Thadeous can find his inner hero, he can help his brother prevent the destruction of his land. Stay a slacker, and not only does he die a coward, he gets front row seats to the dawn of an all-new Dark Ages.
  - Written by Universal Pictures" -IMDb

